# Non-Repudiation vs Identity-Binding

Tags: signature, security-definition, non-repudiation

There are 3 properties offered by a cryptographic digital signature scheme:

1. Integrity guarantee of the message signed.
2. Authenticity guarantee of the message signed.
3. Non-repudiation of the message by the signer.

Property 1 and 2 are also offered by MACs and can be described in one word. The 3rd property is a bit special - not only is it only meaningful in cryptographic sense as non-repudiation in legal sense has whole another range of requirements, but also (as you might have guessed it), it's described in 2 words (one of which is a negation).

So I have the following questions in my mind:

1. Is the "non-repudiation" property ever described using other terms in any literature? Such as the that in the title of this post - "identity-binding"?
2. Does using such terminology change the semantic function of digital signature?

Comment: I'm missing in "identity binding" the idea that there was a conscious decision to sign a particular document. You could bind your identity to something without such a decision I suppose. There is a reason why non-rep using digital signatures / smart cards *always* require you to enter the PIN, while this may not be necessary for e.g. authentication.

Comment: Actually, non-repudiation is not matched by identity binding at all. The main idea is that you have a transferable proof that the owner of a private key authored a message. Sure, this somewhat binds it to a public key but not to an arbitrary identity, yet. There PKI problems get mixed in. And no, not aware of another or a one word term in your sense (most people will consider non-repudiation a single word).